# Refresh issue on ControlsFX CheckComboBox display

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, controlsfx

I'm learning API JavaFX for an application I'm working on at the moment and I am trying  to use the `CheckComboBox` from ControlsFX.

I've made a test in order to resolve a problem about items display refresh when I add items in the `ObservableList` which populates the `CheckComboBox`.

```
import org.controlsfx.control.CheckComboBox;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Testin extends Application {
    private Stage main;
    private FlowPane root;
    private ObservableList<String> l;

    public Testin(){
        root = new FlowPane();
        l = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        l.add("bla");
        l.add("shablagoo");
        l.add("tirelipimpon");
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        main = primaryStage;
        CheckComboBox<String> test = new CheckComboBox<>();
        test.getItems().addAll(l);
        Button btn = new Button("test");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event){
                l.add("ok");
                System.out.println("ok");
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(test);
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        main.setScene(scene);
        main.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Like a classic `ComboBox`, when an item is added to the list, it would refresh itself automatically but it's not the case.
Do I have to create a `ListChangeListener` which, at each modification report this on the displayed `ComboBox` list, or is my code wrong ?

Additional information: I also try this test with a `ComboBox`, replacing the `CheckComboBox` and that runs well.

Comment: If you change `CheckComboBox` to `ComboBox`, it still fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test.getItems().addAll(someList);
```

[copies all the elements of `someList` to the combo box's items list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-). Clearly, subsequent changes to `someList` won't have any effect on the combo box.

You either want to replace

```
test.getItems().addAll(l);
```

with

```
test.setItems(l);
```

***or*** you want to replace

```
l.add("ok");
```

with

```
test.getItems().add("ok");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is a problem with the CheckComboBox. It doesn't have the method .setItems() instead of basic ComboBox. In fact, in my test, the button add and updates the initial list, but as the combobox items list doesn't point to this, it cannot be updated, right ?

Comment: So use the second solution: replace `l.add("ok");` with `test.getItems().add("ok");`.